# What are the key terms rvalue and lvalue?

Tags: c, terminology

Many of the times my compiler shows errors like Lvalue or Rvalue Required.

What are the **Lvalues** and **Rvalues** in **C or any  programming languages**?

Is a pointer constant a rvalue?

Comment: Regarding "any programming languages", this differs a lot. Take Python for example, where you can do stuff like `a, b = getTuple()`.

Comment: question seems more appropriate for SO

Answer (score 8):

The terms are somewhat language-specific; they were first introduced in [CPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931006/). Being an lvalue or an rvalue is a property of an *expression*; that is, every expression is either an lvalue or an rvalue.

You will often find explanations that deal with the left and right side of an assignment. That is the historical origin of the letters l and r in *lvalue* and *rvalue*, but it does not hold anymore. For example, there are lvalues that can *not* stand on the left side of an assignment (expressions denoting arrays and constant variables come to mind, but also class types where the assignment operator has been hidden or deleted), and at least in C++, there are rvalues that *can* stand on the left side of an assignment.

The best definition that I know of is: an lvalue is an expression to which the unary `&` operator *can* be applied, whereas an rvalue is an expression to which the unary `&` operator can *not* be applied. (This is not entirely true in C++ if you overload said operator, but that's probably very bad practice.)

Since C++11, the language also has the notions of *xvalues*, *prvales* und *glvalues* (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609968/)).

> Is pointer constant is a rvalue?

Expressions that denote pointer *variables* like `p` are lvalues. Expressions that denote pointer *values* like `&i` are rvalues. Both of them can be either `const` or `non-const`; that's completely orthogonal.

Java doesn't have the notion of lvalues, but in §15.1 the Language Specification states:

> When an expression in a program is evaluated (executed), the result denotes one
>   of three things:
>
> 1. A variable (§4.12) (**in C, this [expression] would be called an lvalue**)
> 2. A value (§4.2, §4.3)
> 3. Nothing (the expression is said to be void)